# Можно ли подключить к Android Studio сразу несколько git репозиториев

Tags: android-studio, git, gradle

Есть проект из трех модулей. Каждый в отдельном репозитории. Они собраны в проект remote тобишь в settings.gradle они собраны так:

```
include ':app'
include ':lib1'
project(':lib1').projectDir = new File('somepath1/lib1')
include ':lib2'
project(':lib2').projectDir = new File('somepath2/lib2')
```

В таком виде в проекте доступен только git репозиторий текущего модуля(чтобы комитить, смотреть изменения и прочее нужно открывать/переключать модули отдельно). Возможно есть настройки или плагин позволяющий не переключаясь между проектами работать с репозиторием каждого из модулей из одного проекта?

из того что я знаю можно использовать  сабтри от самого GIT https://help.github.com/articles/about-git-subtree-merges/ но к примеру Xcode спокойно поддерживает модули с разными репозиториями.

Comment: Не знаю, что там конкретно в Android Studio, но AOSP состоит из 100500 репозиториев, которые находятся в одном сете. Управляет этим всем утилита `repo` с помощью manifest файлов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дополнительные репозитории можно подключть в android studio "File->Settings->Version Control". Не подключенные репозитории будут показаны серым можно выбрать любой и нажать "+" справа вверху.